# upload csv and save it to a local folder Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

What I would like to have happen is a when a user uploads a CSV from an HTML page that file should save to a local directory that I have provided.

One of two things should happen, if the file already exists it should overwrite, otherwise it should create a new file.

Here is the code that I have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
    $(document).ready(function() {

    // The event listener for the file upload
    document.getElementById('txtFileUpload').addEventListener('change', upload, false);

    // Method that checks that the browser supports the HTML5 File API
    function browserSupportFileUpload() {
        var isCompatible = false;
        if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
        isCompatible = true;
        }
        return isCompatible;
    }

    // Method that reads and processes the selected file
    function upload(evt) {
        if (!browserSupportFileUpload()) {
            alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser!');
            } else {
                var data = null;
                var file = evt.target.files[0];
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsText(file);
                reader.onload = function(event) {
                    var csvData = event.target.result;
                    data = $.csv.toArrays(csvData);
                    if (data && data.length > 0) {
                    alert('Imported -' + data.length + '- rows successfully!');
                    } else {
                        alert('No data to import!');
                    }
                };
                reader.onerror = function() {
                    alert('Unable to read ' + file.fileName);
                };
            }
        }
    });
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dvImportSegments" class="fileupload ">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Upload your CSV File</legend>
        <input type="file" name="File Upload" id="txtFileUpload" accept=".csv" />
    </fieldset>
    </div>
 
<script>
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML;
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say local, do you mean the clients computer or the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need a server (PHP or NodeJS) that exposes this html file ( usually placed in a public folder ) and then serve this html file, you can then do the validation and the storage through the server. You could later on add a database hook, but that depends on your needs and probably the amount of data you'll be uploading.